# Getting Unauthorised 401 for my nextjs 13 app on Search Console

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console, next.js13, unauthorized, clerk

I built out a nextjs 13 webapp using clerk for auth. The issue is that the homepage of the web app isn't discoverable on Google. when i Test Live URL, this is how it looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00GcL.png)

I've done basic implementation of seo in the app. But i see this in vercel whenever i try to crawl the website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJt6.png)

I suspected Clerk Middleware is the issue, but i've added homepage in  public routes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inTOY.png)

If someone can help, that'd be very helpful!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting Unauthorized using Clerk middleware as well, but I couldn't figure out a solution, so I just went back to the previous middleware version and everything worked fine.

```
import { withClerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export default withClerkMiddleware((req: NextRequest) => {
  return NextResponse.next();
});

// Stop Middleware running on static files
export const config = { matcher:  '/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico).*)',};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using Clerk's Middleware. If that's the case then this error is caused by the fact that you are on the development version instead of production.